# Multilevel Menu-Submenu-Option bashscript ( If-Else vs Switch-Case )

Tags: shell-script, menu

I'm asking for suggestion which one is better for Menu-Option especially for the process after you choose option it will have a option back to the menu.

Please see below

```
[Menu]
1 - Option 1
2 - Option 2
3 - Quit (exit command)

Please choose option:

#Under Option 1
1 - Sub-Option 1
2 - Sub-Option 2
3 - back to main menu

#Under Sub-Option 1
1 - Sub-sub Option 1
2 - Sub-sub Option 2 
3 - back to Sub-option menu
```

any suggestion?Tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`switch..case` is most suitable when there is more than one choice for readability and maintainability (adding options).

In terms of performance, both are pretty much the same.